# Views Count with multiple fields

Tags: views

I have 2 fields that each can have multiple values. I want to count the number of values for a given content type (Actions). Using aggregation everything works fine when the display/view has one field but when I add subsequent fields the results do not come close to adding up.

Record 1 => Field a has 2 values selected, field b has 4
Record 2 => Field a has 4 values selected, field b has 6

Result should be ... Field a = 6 and Field b = 10

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Views, can't you use the delta value of the field? It should give you the amount of fields-a & fields-b per node. If you have 2 value's in field a. `field a:delta` = 2. From there you should be able to aggregate over several nodes.

It won't give you the value's of the selected fields though.